# How to remove the extra spaces before the cell text?

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

I am working with WinForms. In my application, I need to use RTF for formatting cell text. However, when I set the RTF style, there are extra spaces shown before the text in the first cell. Here is the sample code I used:

```
string rtf3 =
    @"{\rtf1\ansi" +
    // font table
    @"{\fonttbl" +
    @"\f0 Axel;} " +
    @"\deff0 " +
    // color table
    @"{\colortbl" +
    @"\red186\green0\blue0; " +
    @"\red240\green224\blue255;} " +
    // first line
    @"\ql\f0\fs18 " + "David" +
    @"\plain\par" +
    // closing bracket
    @"}";
```

In this, I can't understand the style settings. Please anyone suggest me how to resolve the extra spaces as per the below image?

[image: screenshot of form]

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: At least provide valid rtf, which can be open. Not only working with rtf is hell, but you are making it even worse !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the spaces that are not part of an RTF control word that you do not want to appear in the output. So spaces after `;` and `}`, and before `{`. So your code will look like this:

```
string rtf3 =
    @"{\rtf1\ansi" +
    // font table
    @"{\fonttbl" +
    @"\f0 Axel;}" +
    @"\deff0" +
    // color table
    @"{\colortbl" +
    @"\red186\green0\blue0;" +
    @"\red240\green224\blue255;}" +
    // first line
    @"\ql\f0\fs18 " + "David" +
    @"\plain\par" +
    // closing bracket
    @"}";
```